# async / await run async functions sequentially in nodejs, puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, puppeteer

## Problem

I have 3 functions which are dependent of one another and therefore I would want them to run sequentially. The function called are async and return promise and it takes time to run.

## My Code - Index.js

```
#Function One
scrapA.scrap().then(data => {
    readWriteToFile.writeToFile(data, 'scrapA-data-'+timestamp, 'json');
});

#Function Two
compare.compareData('./output/json/data.json', './output/json/scraped-data-'+timestamp+'.json').then(data => {

    let dataWithStockData = data;
    let mapDatas = dataWithStockData.map( obj => { 

        let finalObj = {
            manufacturer: obj.manufacturer,
            grade: obj.condition,
            carrier: obj.carrier,
            stock: obj.stock,
        }
        return finalObj;
    });

#Function Three
readWriteToFile.writeToFile(data, 'data-with-stock-'+timestamp, 'csv'); });
```

## My Code - compare.js

```
async function compareData(models, competitorsData) {

try {
    
    const modelsArr = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(models, { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' }));
    const competitorsDataArr = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(competitorsData, { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' }));

    //Loop through both array of json data
    modelsArr.forEach((device, deviceKey) => {

        competitorsDataArr.forEach((scrapedData, scrapedDataKey) => {

            
            if (
                    scrapedData.manufacturer.toLowerCase() === data.manufacturer.toLowerCase()
            ) {

                 modelsArr[dataKey]['stk'] = scrapedData.stk;

            }
        })
    });

    return modelsArr;

} catch (error) {

    console.log("Error", error);
    throw error;
}
```

}

## My Code - readWriteToFile.js

```
async function writeToFile(data, filename, type) {

let finalData = '';

if (type == "json") {

    finalData = JSON.stringify(data);

} else if (type == "csv") {

    finalData = arrayToCSV(data);

} else {
    console.log("File type not supported");
    process.exit(1);
}

fs.writeFile("./output/" + type + '/' + filename + '.' + type, finalData, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("File written successfully\n");
    }
});
```

}

## My solution

I simply wrapped all my function calls in async and added await at the front. I does not work and it does not throw any errors.

```
(async () => {
    
    await scraperA.scrap().then(data => {
            console.log("DATA", data);
            readWriteToFile.writeToFile(data, 'scraped-data-'+timestamp, 'json');
        });
    
    await compare.compareData('./output/json/data.json', './output/json/scraped-data-'+timestamp+'.json').then(data => {
        let dataWithStockData = data;
        mapData = dataWithStock.map( obj => { 
    
            let finalObj = {
                manufacturer: obj.manufacturer,
                grade: obj.condition,
                stock: obj.stock,
            }
            return finalObj;
        });
    });

    await readWriteToFile.writeToFile(mapData, 'data-with-stock-'+timestamp, 'csv');

});
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome? and where (if at all?) is mapData declared in your solution?

Comment: You are not calling the function. You have to call the function to make an async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a simple typo (missing `()` after the "IIFE")

Comment: You could avoid the async IIFE by updating your Node.js version. Current versions of Node.js support top-level await: https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await

Comment: If you don't have limit about adding dependencies, [async][1] library offer a very good way to manage these kind of stuff.
In your case i thinks its suitable using the waterfall method, that enables you to use the result data from one call into another, as explained in the docs.


  [1]: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#waterfall

Comment: @jabaa sorry my bad, the "compare.compareData()" call is not async neither is "readWriteToFile.writeToFile()"

Comment: @jabaa added code from other files.

Comment: @FreTimmerman the outcome is to run all 3 parts sequentially: 1) write scraped data to a file, 2) compare data in 2 files 3) get matching data and write to csv file

Comment: What does _"sorry my bad, the `compare.compareData()` call is not async neither is `readWriteToFile.writeToFile()`"_ mean? Do the functions return a promise? Do you want to await the promise? You can use `await` with sync functions. That doesn't cause issues. But you can't use `.then`.

Comment: @jabaa I just had async keyword before the function name, I am not sure if it does anything. I want to execute functions one by one.. currently, I am seeing an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" which is in line 8 of compare.js file and it is because the code "await readWriteToFile.writeToFile(data, 'scraped-data-'+timestamp, 'json');" fails to write any data in the file. if I comment 2nd and 3rd part (which is comparing and writing to csv file) I see part 1 working.

Comment: Your code looks like a script (in contrast to a server). You can use `fs.writeFileSync` instead of `fs.writeFile`. You should never use `*Sync` functions in a server request handler, but you should use them in a script. They make your code simpler and are up to 10 times faster. You should also remove the `async` keyword from `writeToFile` and `compareData`.

Answer (score 2):

The code structure

```
(async () => {
    
    /* your code */

});
```

suggests you want to create an async [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). But you have to invoke it (`()` at the end):

```
(async () => {
    
    /* your code */

})();
```

Using current versions of Node.js you don't need an async IIFE. Node.js supports [top-level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await).

Since `readWriteToFile.writeToFile` and `compare.compareData` don't return a promise, you can't call `.then` and `await` doesn't make sense.

Starting with Node.js v14.8, you can write

```
await scraperA.scrap().then(data => {
    console.log("DATA", data);
    readWriteToFile.writeToFile(data, 'scraped-data-'+timestamp, 'json');
});

const dataWithStockData = compare.compareData('./output/json/data.json', './output/json/scraped-data-'+timestamp+'.json')
mapData = dataWithStock.map( obj => { 

    let finalObj = {
        manufacturer: obj.manufacturer,
        grade: obj.condition,
        stock: obj.stock,
    }
    return finalObj;
});

readWriteToFile.writeToFile(mapData, 'data-with-stock-'+timestamp, 'csv');
```

After you fixed the problem, you could consider using either `.then` or `await` / `async` to clean up your code. Mixing them is usually considered bad code style.

```
const data = await scraperA.scrap();
console.log("DATA", data);
readWriteToFile.writeToFile(data, 'scraped-data-'+timestamp, 'json');

const dataWithStockData = compare.compareData('./output/json/data.json', './output/json/scraped-data-'+timestamp+'.json');

mapData = dataWithStock.map( obj => { 

  let finalObj = {
    manufacturer: obj.manufacturer,
    grade: obj.condition,
    stock: obj.stock,
  }
  return finalObj;
});

readWriteToFile.writeToFile(mapData, 'data-with-stock-'+timestamp, 'csv');
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to answer without knowing which of the functions you are calling are synchronous or not. But making the following assumptions:

- readWriteToFile.writeToFile returns a Promise (or it is async)
- mapData is defined elsewhere

You must:

- Add a return statement to the last line of the first `.then(...)` block
- As jabaa said, you have to actually invoke the function.

```js
(async () => {
    
    await scraperA.scrap().then(data => {
            console.log("DATA", data);
            return readWriteToFile.writeToFile(data, 'scraped-data-'+timestamp, 'json');
        });
    
    await compare.compareData('./output/json/data.json', './output/json/scraped-data-'+timestamp+'.json').then(data => {
        let dataWithStockData = data;
        mapData = dataWithStock.map( obj => { 
    
            let finalObj = {
                manufacturer: obj.manufacturer,
                grade: obj.condition,
                stock: obj.stock,
            }
            return finalObj;
        });
    });

    await readWriteToFile.writeToFile(mapData, 'data-with-stock-'+timestamp, 'csv');

})();
```

Comment: sorry my bad, the "compare.compareData()" call is not async neither is "readWriteToFile.writeToFile()". let me show the code in other 2 files

Comment: Seeing the other code, while the functions are not asynchronous because of the content (inside there are only synchronous code), you have made them asynchronous because you marked them as `async`. As such, they return a Promise, and you must still await for them. And I think the solution (adding the return before the first call to writeToFile) is still relevant. Did it work? It's good to give feedback.